# How you check intertnet off or on every 10 minutes without using broadcast manager

Tags: android

after every 10 minuted i want to checked whether internet is off or on. if on i want to send  data to server if off i want to save data internally, when again on the internally save data send to server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using BroadcastReceiver is a better approach as it will help you in saving device resources. However, if you're willing to go for a alternative, you can try out the following code:

```
private int duration = 10 * 60 * 1000; //for 10 minutes

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   handler = new Handler();
   handler.postDelayed(networkCheckRunnable,duration);
}

Runnable networkCheckRunnable = new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
     ConnectivityManager manager = (ConnectivityManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
     NetworkInfo info = manager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
     if(info!=null && info.isConnected()){
        //your logic when network is connected
     }else{
        //your logic when network is not connected
     }
     handler.postDelayed(networkCheckRunnable,duration);
   }
};
```

Comment: This only checks if there is a wifi connection. It has nothing to do with an internet connection.

Comment: I believe it checks for active internet connection whether it's cellular or WiFi.

Comment: The point is you could be connected to wifi with no internet, and this would read that situation as connected.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent background = new Intent(context, BackgroundService.class);
        context.startService(background);
    }

}
```

The above code is our broadcast receiver. Every time it is called, our background service is executed.

So how do we enable our broadcast receiver to work on Android’s alarm service? That is easy, and can be seen in the following chunk of code:

```
public class ExampleActivity extends Activity {

    private Context context;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        this.context = this;
        Intent alarm = new Intent(this.context, AlarmReceiver.class);
        boolean alarmRunning = (PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.context, 0, alarm, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE) != null);
        if(alarmRunning == false) {
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.context, 0, alarm, 0);
            AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
            alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime(), 600000, pendingIntent);
        }
    }

}
```

The above code will prepare our broadcast receiver and then check to see if it is already running. If it is already running, do nothing because we don’t want to register it multiple times. If the receiver is not already running, we will register it to repeat every 600000 milliseconds, or every 10 minutes.

So what exactly is the broadcast receiver doing when it wakes up? It is just calling our background service intent where we do all of our heavy lifting.

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service {

    private boolean isRunning;
    private Context context;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        this.context = this;
        this.isRunning = false;
        this.backgroundThread = new Thread(myTask);
    }

    private Runnable myTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // Do something here
            stopSelf();
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        this.isRunning = false;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        if(!this.isRunning) {
            this.isRunning = true;
            this.backgroundThread.start();
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml file. The following lines must be added to your file:

```
<application>
    <service android:name=".BackgroundService" />
    <receiver android:name="AlarmReceiver"></receiver>
</application>
```